# Android project not obfuscating

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate my android code, I have set minifienable true and setup proguard file, but after generating apk and decompile, the code is not obfuscated. This is my proguard :

my proguard file:

```
-dontwarn com.huawei.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.*
-dontwarn org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.*
-dontwarn org.openjsse.net.ssl.OpenJSSE
```

my build.gradle file

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug{
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are not decompiling debug apk by any chance?

Comment: check the build folder whether has outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt

Comment: The same thing is happening to me as well. The peculiar thing is that even if minifyEnabled true and the same rule in proguardFile is used, I can see obfuscated code in the release build type, but not in the debug build type.

Answer (score 0):

To enable ProGuard in Android Studio. Below is the sample how to enable default ProGuard in Android Studio.

1. Go to the build.gradle file of app
2. enable the proguard minifyEnabled true and useProguard true
3. enable shrinkResources true to reduce the APK size by shrinking resources.
4. proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt') to enable the default one. If you want to use your own proguard file then use the below rules.

   ```
    release
    {
        debuggable false
        useProguard true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   ```

Comment: tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

1. delete build file
2. invalidate cache and restart android studio